# Can't access folders created by rsync on qnap server

Tags: rsync, qnap

I'm trying to use RSync to backup my files to my QNap Turbo Nas.

I have activated the rsync service and created a private shared folder named "RSync". On my Windows machine I mapped a network drive to that share (Y:). I created a folder on that share for each machine I wanted to backup.

Then I executed the following command:

```
rsync -rtv /cygdrive/c/data rsync://user:password@qnap/RSync/laptop
```

It succesfully copied all the files in the data folder to the qnap server. It created a folder called "data" under "laptop".

However, when I open drive Y: and go into the folder "laptop", when I try to open "data" I get an "access denied" error.

In the rsync configuration on qnap you have to specify a username and password. I tried to use that username/password to logon to qnap/RSync, but it refused. It also wouldn't let me connect directly to qnap/RSync/laptop/data. Then I reconfigured the username/password on rsync to be the same as the username/password that I can connect to qnap/RSync with and ran rsync again (after first destroying the private shared folder and creating it again). I could connect to qnap/Rsync using that username/password. I could go into folder "laptop", but it still refused me acces to folder "data".

What do I need to do so that rsync can backup each machine to its own folder on the shared folder on the qnap server, and also using the windows shell I can go into those backups and open each of the folders and files?

Comment: Duh. Just use the admin username and password. I got the idea a few hours later and it worked just fine. However, I would still be interested to know if there is a way without using the admin account.